# How to compare two dictionaries `Dictionary<string`, int> and `Dict_Aggregate= `Dictionary<string`, string>` using c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there any way to compare Dict =  `Dictionary<string, int>` and Dict_Aggregate= `Dictionary<string, string>` using c#.
Please note that both the dictionary is generating same output.
Please suggest.
currently i am doing it this way :

```
bool dictionariesEqual = Dict.Keys.Count == Dict_Aggregate.Keys.Count && Dict.Keys.All(k => Dict_Aggregate.ContainsKey(k) && object.Equals(Dict_Aggregate[k], Dict[k]));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: How do you want to compare the `int` and `string` values?

Comment: Please describe how you want to compare them.  What information do you want?  Show some examples with sample input/output.  Do you want to know just if they're equal, do you want to know which items are in one and not another, do you want to know which keys have different values, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to do some more extensive comparison, and it depends on whether you care that the values are the same.

This

```
bool dictionariesEqual = Dict.Keys.Count == Dict_Aggregate.Keys.Count 
    && Dict.Keys.All(k => Dict_Aggregate.ContainsKey(k);
```

will determine that the keys match; if you want to match the values, you'll have to add another clause and determine how to compare the `int`s and `string`s, something like:

```
bool dictionariesEqual = Dict.Keys.Count == Dict_Aggregate.Keys.Count 
    && Dict.Keys.All(k => Dict_Aggregate.ContainsKey(k) 
    && Dict_Aggregate.All(v => 
      { int test; 
        return int.TryParse(v.Value, out test) 
          && Dict[v.Key].Equals(test); });
```

Obviously there are some edge cases on that last value comparison - it kind of depends on the `string` values being the exact number, and having no spaces, etc. However, you can refine that if you need to.

Comment: I would be careful of just calling `ToString()` depending on the culture the strings may not match. You may be better off doing a TryParse on the int.

Comment: Yeah - there are a lot of edge cases there. I was just going for something to demonstrate the concept of finding a way to compare the `int`s and `string`s.

Comment: I would replace the last `Dict.Values.All` with `Dict_Aggregate.All(v => 
{ int test;
  return int.TryParse(v.Value, out test) && Dict[v.Key].Equals(test);
});` (I did not just want to edit your question and it was not different enough to warrent another answer.)

Comment: Fair enough - that's a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Fair Enough to proceed